# Magento date format issue soap order API

Tags: web-services, magento, soap

I have got order information from soap Mangeto api. all information I get correct but I get created_at, updated_at date field wrong.

I get created_at value 2014-02-18 11:36:06 but it will be 2014-02-18 17:06:06.

I have been finding the answer to spent several hours. Magento API returns all date values in GMT. I have set Timezone = India Standard Time (Asia/Calcutta)   (GTM 5.30+) in admin . website got change but web service are still returning GMT time.

anyone have idea how to get date format in given timezone in soap web service.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient( SOAP_CLIENT_URL );
$sessionId = $proxy->login( SOAP_CLIENT_USERNAME, SOAP_CLIENT_PASSWORD );

$result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'order.list',array(
                array('customer_id'=>2)));
```

Can we set any param in order web service? or Magento has any other way to solve the problem.